# Define a worksheet name and a WorksheetRange

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-excel

Im trying to use the Linq to Excel library, and i get stucked into this problem.

I have an excel with a worksheet name, and i need to define the range of the colums that i need to get.

The problem is: how to use these two classes at the same time on query?

```
excel.Worksheet<Company>("NAME OF WORKSHEET")
```

and

```
excel.WorksheetRange<Company>("B37", "M37")
```

Example:

```
 var print = from c in excel.WorksheetRange<Company>("B37", "M37")
             select c;
```

(but i cant do this, because i need to set the worksheet name first)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the worksheet name as the 3rd argument in the `WorksheetRange<>()` method.

```
var print = from c in excel.WorksheetRange<Company>("B37", "M37", "NAME OF WORKSHEET")
            select c;
```